# http socket request returning trailling characters

Tags: c, sockets, http

I am learning network programming in C and tried to create to a toy version of wget.

However, when I run the program, I get the page with some trailing characters at the beginning and at the end (0 & f43 in this case).

The program contains two .c and two .h files.

One for parsing (naïvely) the address and the other to make the network request
and dump the data.

Here are the files for parsing the input:

**url.h**

```
#ifndef URL_H
#define URL_H

/* information of an URL*/
struct url_info
{
    char* url; //full url
    char* protocol; // protocol type: http, ftp, etc...
    char* host; // host name
    int port;   //port number
    char* path; //path
};
typedef struct url_info url_info;

static const char P_HTTP[] = "http";

void parse_url(char* url, url_info *info);

void exit_with_error(char* message);

void print_url_info(url_info info);

#endif //URL_H
```

**url.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"url.h"


void parse_url(char* url, url_info *info)
{
    // url format: [http://]<hostname>[:<port>]/<path>

    char *full_url = malloc((strlen(url) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  char *protocol;
  char *path;
  char *host;
  int port;

  strcpy(full_url, url);
    info->url = full_url;

  char *protocol_token = strstr(url, "://");
  if (protocol_token){
    protocol = url;
    *protocol_token = '\0';
    url = protocol_token + 3;
  } else {
    protocol = "http";
  }
    info->protocol = protocol;

  char *port_token = strstr(url, ":");
  char *path_token = strstr(url, "/");

  if (port_token && port_token < path_token){
        port = atoi(port_token + 1);
        *port_token = '\0';
  } else {
    port = 80;
  }
    info->port = port;

  if (path_token){
    *path_token = '\0';
    host = url;
    path = path_token + 1;
        info->host = host;
        info->path = path;
  } else {
    exit_with_error("No trailing /.");
  }
}


void print_url_info(url_info info){
    printf("The URL contains following information: \n");
    printf("Full url:\t%s\n", info.url);
    printf("Protocol type:\t%s\n", info.protocol);
    printf("Host name:\t%s\n", info.host);
    printf("Port No.:\t%d\n", info.port);
    printf("Path:\t\t%s\n", info.path);
}


void exit_with_error(char *message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here are the files for making the request

**wgetX.h**

```
#ifndef WGETX_H_
#define WGETX_H_

#define B_SIZE 1024 * 5000

void write_data(const char *path, const char *data);

char* download_page(url_info info, char *buff);

char* http_get_request(char* path, char* host);

char* read_http_reply(char* recv_buf_t);

unsigned long ipfromhost(const char *host);

#endif
```

**wgetX.c**

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <string.h>

#include "url.h"
#include "wgetX.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    url_info info;


    if (argc != 2) {
        exit_with_error("The wgetX must have exactly 1 parameter as input. \n");
    }
    char *url = argv[1];
    parse_url(url, &info);

    char *buf;
    buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*B_SIZE);
    bzero(buf, B_SIZE);

    download_page(info, buf);
  printf("%s", buf);

    free(buf);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char* download_page(url_info info, char *buf)
{
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    int len, sz, mysocket;
    char *request = http_get_request(info.path, info.host);

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = ipfromhost(info.host);
    dest.sin_port = htons(info.port);
    connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    send(mysocket, request, strlen(request), 0);

    len = 0;
    sz = 0;
    do {
        len = recv(mysocket, buf + sz, B_SIZE - sz, 0);
        if (len == -1) {continue;}
        sz += len;
    } while (len > 0);

    *(buf + sz) = '\0';

  close(mysocket);
    return buf;
}


char* http_get_request(char* path, char* host) {
    char * request_buffer = (char *) malloc(1024);
    memset(request_buffer, 0, sizeof(*request_buffer));
    snprintf(request_buffer, 1024, "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n",
            path, host);
    return request_buffer;
}

unsigned long ipfromhost(const char *host){
  struct in_addr **addr_list;
  struct hostent *he;
  if ((he = gethostbyname(host)) != NULL){
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++){
      return addr_list[i]->s_addr;
    }
    exit_with_error("Couldn't resolve host to ip adress\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
    exit_with_error("Couldn't resolve host to ip adress\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**Makefile**

```
LINK_TARGET = wgetX
OBJS = \
    wgetX.o \
    url.o
REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)
all : $(LINK_TARGET)
clean:
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    cc -g -o $@ $^

%.o : %.c
    cc -g  -Wall -o $@ -c $<

wgetX.o : wgetX.h url.h
url.o : url.h
```

When executing the program on one specific url, I get an html output that is different from the source code (as found in Chrome). I get garbage characters: a zero at the end and "f43" just before the start of the html

**Commands**

```
make clean
make
./wgetX http://www.google.com/
```

**Output**

I got the http reply message with the status code and all and just before "

Comment: That's way too much code to wade through but I bet you aren't properly zero terminating a string somewhere.

Comment: Also, why not just use libcurl or the like if you want to talk to a http server?

Comment: I suppose it would be easier. This is for school so I have to use sockets this way. It's for learning purposes!

Comment: regarding: `cc -g  -Wall -o $@ -c $<`  strongly suggest: `cc -g  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -o $@ -c $<`  This enables the main `warning` features.  Which when applied to the posted code will result in several warning messages being output by the compiler.  Those warnings need to be corrected

Comment: OT: regarding function: `exit_with_error()`, the statement: `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);`  this does not tell the user why  the error occurred.  Suggest using `perror()` where approporiate.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (argc != 2) {
        exit_with_error("The wgetX must have exactly 1 parameter as input. \n");`  typically, when the number of command line parameters is not correct, a USAGE message is displayed to the user, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE %s <URL>\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*B_SIZE);`  When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Also, the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `len = recv(mysocket, buf + sz, B_SIZE - sz, 0);
        if (len == -1) {continue;}`  Once the call to `recv()` fails, (since nothing has changed) it will probably continue to fail.  Better to call `perror()`, cleanup, and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `len = recv(mysocket, buf + sz, B_SIZE - sz, 0);`  This will not expand to what you are expecting.  Suggest: `len = recv(mysocket, buf + sz, (B_SIZE) - sz, 0);`  However, this: `#define B_SIZE 1024 * 5000` should have been written as: `#define B_SIZE (1024 * 5000)`

Comment: OT: in the definition of `struct URL` the field: `int port` should be declared as: `unsigned short port`

Comment: OT: regarding: `static const char P_HTTP[] = "http";`  The array: `P_HTTP[]` is unused and could be removed.

Comment: in function: `parse_url()`  this declaration: ` int port;` should be: `short unsigned port;`  so, of course, this: `port = atoi(port_token + 1);` should be: `port = (short unsigned)atoi(port_token + 1);`  Also, `atoi()` does not indicate if it was successful, suggest using `strtol()`

Comment: regarding: `len = recv(mysocket, buf + sz, (B_SIZE) - sz, 0);`  the function: `recv()` returns a type: `ssize_t`, so the variable `len` (and associated variables) should be declared as `ssize_t`

Comment: when calling C library functions, like `mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`, should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` and `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` so the user is informed of a problem occurrence and why it occurred

Answer (score 1):

> I get garbage characters: a zero at the end and "f43" just before the start of the html

Welcome to the wonderful world of HTTP. Please note that HTTP is not a trivial protocol even though it might look like this. It should say something that the HTTP/1.1 standard as initially published in [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) has 176 pages text.

What you likely see here is chunked transfer encoding of the content. In this encoding the content is not transferred as one single piece but in several chunks, each prefixed by the length (in hex). I.e. something like this:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 ok
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

 a
 0123456789
 12
 These are 18 bytes
 0
```

In your specific case the initial f43 *"just before the start of the html"* is the length of the following chunk (f43 in hex of 3907 in decimal) and the *"zero at the end"* is the length of the final chunk (0).

For more on this see [section 3.6.1 in RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1) or [section 4.1 in RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1).

Comment: Thank you! Can I force that the transfer-encoding not be chunked?

Comment: @aripy887: As long as you claim to support `HTTP/1.1` you must support chunked encoding. If you instead only use `HTTP/1.0` in your request then the server cannot use chunked encoding since this is only defined with `HTTP/1.1`.